# PHP / MySQL storing and searching dates

Tags: php, mysql

Like many people, I am totally confused by the many date functions in PHP and MySQL. What I need is a to be able to store a date in MySQL and be able to view it on the screen in a human readable format, search on it by month, year, or combination of both using a standard web form, or sort it on months or years.

Example search would be all the records for febuary for the past 5 years.

I have a javascript calendar that inputs the month in the form as 02-12-2011.

What is the best format to use for this. What should the field be in MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please make use of the DateTime object.

Store the dates in mysql as a `DATE` format.

When writing the data

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['date']);

or

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['date']);

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `data` SET `date` = '%s'", $date->format('Y-m-d'))
```

When reading the data out create a DateTime object.

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
```

Then you can print it in whatever format you want, e.g. You javascript's format:

```
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

See

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

and for date formats:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

As far as searches go, you can use mysql Date functions on the fields.

For all records in February for the last 5 years.

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 2 AND YEAR(`date`) >= YEAR(NOW()) - 5
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Also, note that `DateTime` class is available only on PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: Its actually available in 5.2 onwards, but some of the functions are 5.3+

Comment: This is what I have, but it is causeing a few problems and this is why I asked. First: MySQL stores the date as YYYY-MM-DD and the javascript enters it as DD-MM-YYYY (which is what I would like). I am converting it, but a real pain. The other problem is this. At time this may be an empty field and I would want it to just be empty, but I guess because it is a date field if there is nothing there it automatically enters 0000-00-000, which messes things up.

Comment: I was doing some convaluded conversion, but I see above it should not be that hard. Going to change some code around and see how that works. Thanks

Comment: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['date']); gives this error:   Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: Using version 5.3.2 on windows for testing, but production will be PHP Version 5.2.15 - so it may not work. I would prefer somthing that is a little more backwards compatible.

Comment: have you done something to $_POST['date'] before hand? It seems that it is a DateTime object. $_POST['date'] should just be the 'd-m-Y' format. maybe try `var_dump($_POST['date'])` Otherwise the error is from a different line.

Comment: Nope, the error is from that line. If I put it in the error happens remove it, no error. $_POST['date'] is from a form which for testing purposes is hardcoded in. <input ..... value='date('d-m-Y')'>

Answer (score 1):

The column type in MySQL should be `date`.

Comment: which will be formatted as `YYYY-mm-dd` so on the php side you need to converts this to how you want it formatted (you could do it in mysql directly too but generally you dont want to do that unless you need to perform some kind of date math/comparison directly in the query)

Answer (score 0):

it's a date, so store it as a DATE column. You can either use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in your SQL query or strtotime in PHP, to convert this back to a value that can be passed in to the php date() function, to output whatever format date you'd like.